# rails model mixed of mongodb and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

I have an mysql table called "info_item", which can be extended with a mongodb document:

```
class CreateInfoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :info_items do |t|
      t.integer     :machine_id
      t.binary      :external_id
      t.integer     :info_type_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The field "external_id" is going to be an id of a mongodb document.

How can I represent it in my model? 
I thought about an object which is inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` and includes the `Mongoid::Document`:

```
class InfoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class PhoneNumber < InfoItem
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

Is it going to run? Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off hooking them together by hand. Both `ActiveRecord::Base` and `Mongoid::Document` will try to define all the usual ORM-ish methods so they will be fighting each other; `ActiveRecord::Base` will also try to do STI with that set up and you don't have any use for STI here.

Don't use `binary` for the `external_id`, AR will probably end up trying to serialize the `BSON::ObjectId` into YAML and you'll end up with a bunch of confusing garbage. Instead, store the `BSON::ObjectId` as a 24 character string:

```
t.string :external_id, :limit => 24
```

and say things like:

```
info_item.external_id = some_mongoid_document.id.to_s
```

and manually implement the usual relation methods:

```
def external
  external_id ? WhateverTheMongoidClassIs.find(external_id) : nil
end

def external=(e)
  self.external_id = e ? e.id.to_s : nil
end
```

You might want to override `external_id=` to stringify inputs as needed and `external_id` to `BSON::Object_id.from_string` outputs too.

I work with mixed PostgreSQL and MongoDB apps and this is the approach I use, works fine and keeps everything sensible in both databases.

Comment: I think my approach will be staying with AR model and adding methods to fetch the mongo data. I'll update about my changes when done.
 Thanks for your tips!